# Dot net core: Persist GeoJson into Postgis get invalid GeoJson representation error

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, postgis, geojson

I am reading this [GeoJsonFile](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/3dZ82WNkR9/) and I convert it to geoJson string:

```
 // parse the GeoJSON string into a FeatureCollection object
var featureCollection = geoJsonReader.Read<FeatureCollection>(geoJsonString);
```

I get 1 feature of Features:

```
IFeature relatedGeoJsonFeature = new Feature();
foreach (var feature in featureCollection)
{
    // get the properties of the feature
    var properties = feature.Attributes;
    var id = properties["id"] as string;
    if (id == $"{element.type + "/" + element.id}")
    {
        relatedGeoJsonFeature = feature;
    }
}
```

and make it into a string

```
var writer = new GeoJsonWriter();
var jsonString = writer.Write(relatedGeoJsonFeature);
```

I want to save it into my Postgis string with geometry type :

```
@"
   INSERT INTO  public.""Cities"" (""geometry"",""jsonGeo"",""parentType"",""parentId"") 
                     values (ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(@geometry), @jsonGeo::text::jsonb,@parentType,@parentId);"

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@geometry", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text, jsonString);
```

[image]

But I got this error :

```
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): XX000: invalid GeoJson representation
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.ReadMessageLong(Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at EazyCityCA.Services.CityStoreClass.Run() in /Users/alt/Projects/MyProjects/eazy_city/EazyCityCore/EazyCityCA/Services/CityStoreClass.cs:line 108
  Exception data:
    Severity: ERROR
    SqlState: XX000
    MessageText: invalid GeoJson representation
    File: lwgeom_pg.c
    Line: 340
    Routine: pg_error
XX000: invalid GeoJson representation
```

Comment: I am not familiar with asp / .net but are you sure that only the geometry part is passed to ST_GeomFromGeoJSON? As shown in the [example](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html) :  `SELECT ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-48.23456,20.12345]}')`

Comment: In this example the type is point but I am trying to send  feature @MughtyWinky

Comment: To clarify my comment:
`SELECT ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('"{type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-48.23456,20.12345][... ...]]]}');` should work


`SELECT ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"Feature","id":"way/100000","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-48.23456,20.12345][... ...]]]}');` won't work

Comment: I am trying to send all JSON, It does mean with a Feaute tag. It seems PG does not support it @MughtyWinky

Comment: Yes, only the geometry part is needed, as the other attributes are represented by additional table columns.